# Black background appears when child form appears

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a drop down menu similar to those of the web, it should start with a wide menu and when clicked it show another wide menu below it, and then at the second menu when you click at any of the keys it shows a drop down menu.

What is supposed to reach programmatically.
[image]

Yet I'm facing too many problems ever since I can't reach with my UI to what HTML/CSS can achieve, fixed too many and couldn't fix this one, but first let me tell you how I created the menu because it will help more to explain the problem.

I used MDI parent to achieve that so I created the first menu as a toolstrip and labels to act as links, made the same with the second menu, at the drop down menu, I couldn't use toolstrip drop down button, because the designer sent me the model with shadow effects and to achieve that I had to use images to cover the form, to sum it up, my current issue is

When I click any of the second menu items to show the drop down menu I noticed a black background right behind the menu until it's fully loaded, and it appears again when I click away to hide it, I suspected that the black color is the form background, so I gave it 100% transparency when I tested it, I found it showing the desktop of windows instead of the black color.

The code for the drop down menu:

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
{
    if (form.GetType() == typeof(Form1))
    {
        form.Activate();
        return;
    }
}

Form1 newForm = new Form1();
newForm.MdiParent = this;
newForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
newForm.Location = new Point(330, 0);
newForm.Show();
```

What is reached programmatically.

[image]

Comment: Can you post what code you have so we can see it?

Comment: And what is your problem? That by giving the background 100% transparency it becomes transparent looks quite reasonable to me...

Comment: Is it possible to show a screenshot?

Comment: Are you using winforms?

Comment: @elgonzo Check the screenshot, I don't want desktop to appear, I want what you see behind the sub-menu to appear.

Comment: @Bolu I added the screenshots

Comment: @MartinLiversage Yes I'm using winforms

Comment: MDI seems like the wrong technology for a menu system.

Comment: @LarsTech and which do you think is better to achieve what I want? as a technology?

Comment: Maybe i misread the screenshots, but it looks like they do not illustrate a problem regarding background or something "behind" the sub menu. It rather seems they show a problem with not rendering the menu item text (in the 2nd screenshot). Or do you mean the green-ish drop-shadow effect around the pull-down menu (which is absent in the first screenshot)?

Answer (score 1):

MDI is probably the wrong technology to use for a menu system.

To show a custom control in a menu system can be accomplished with the ToolStripControlHost and ToolStripDropDown components:

```
void toolStripLabel2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  Control c = new Control();
  c.MinimumSize = new Size(200, 200);      
  c.BackColor = Color.Green;
  ToolStripDropDown td = new ToolStripDropDown();
  td.Padding = Padding.Empty;
  ToolStripControlHost th = new ToolStripControlHost(c);
  th.Margin = Padding.Empty;
  td.Items.Add(th);
  td.Show(this.PointToScreen(new Point(toolStripLabel2.Bounds.Left,
                                       toolStripLabel2.Bounds.Bottom)));
}
```

The drop down will show a shadow effect.

Comment: It's working but when i try set backcolor transparent error happened how i can set transparent in back color

Comment: @MahmoudSamy I don't think the ToolStripControlHost allows transparency.  It sounds like you are just using the wrong technology.  I believe WPF would be better suited for these "graphical design" issues you are having instead of WinForms.